# Is there another way to display a spreadsheet within OpenOffice Writer besides an OLE object?

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I'm writing a paper for college in which I would like to either display or link to a large spreadsheet. I'm using OpenOffice Writer and Calc.

I've tried importing the spreadsheet as an OLE object, however this only displays a small part of the sheet (albeit with scroll bars). I'd like to find a good solution to display the entire sheet, or create a link to the separate file.

I've considered taking a screenshot of the spreadsheet and just importing the image, but this is less than preferred since it would be a static image.

Is there any better way to do this, or am I stuck with using an OLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When embedding the spreadsheet as OLE object, you can **set the size of the OLE object as desired**. To do so, double-click on the object, or right-click and select `Edit`. Now, you can drag the corners and borders of the OLE object to display the entire sheet.

Alternatively, you could **use a hyperlink**. With a hyperlink, you could even select a sheet inside the spreadsheet file as target:

[image: Hyperlink1]

1. Select `Document` as Target;
2. Enter path to document or select the file;
3. Open the targets dialog using the target button:

[image: Select target]

[image: Complete settings for hyperlink]

Comment: Thank you this is some good information. I didn't know about the hyperlink and that should suit my needs well.